# MFC modeless dialog close immediately

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, dialog, modeless

I like to write a modeless dialog based app, but I have a problem. When the program starts, the window close immediately.

The same code works fine when I make a modal dialog. (`DoModal()`)

**Csetkliens.h**

```
#pragma once

#ifndef __AFXWIN_H__
    #error "include 'stdafx.h' before including this file for PCH"
#endif

#include "resource.h"       // main symbols
#include "CsetkliensDlg.h"

class CCsetkliensApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    CCsetkliensApp();
    virtual BOOL InitInstance();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

private:
    CCsetkliensDlg* dlg;
};

extern CCsetkliensApp theApp;
```

**Csetkliens.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Csetkliens.h"
#include "CsetkliensDlg.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CCsetkliensApp, CWinApp)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_HELP, &CWinApp::OnHelp)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

CCsetkliensApp::CCsetkliensApp()
{
    dlg = NULL;
}

CCsetkliensApp theApp;

BOOL CCsetkliensApp::InitInstance()
{
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrls;
    InitCtrls.dwSize = sizeof(InitCtrls);
    InitCtrls.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrls);

    CWinApp::InitInstance();

    if (!AfxSocketInit())
    {
        AfxMessageBox(IDP_SOCKETS_INIT_FAILED);
        return FALSE;
    }

    CShellManager *pShellManager = new CShellManager;

    dlg = new CCsetkliensDlg();
    m_pMainWnd = dlg;
    dlg->Create(CCsetkliensDlg::IDD);
    dlg->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);


    if (pShellManager != NULL)
    {
        delete pShellManager;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

**CsetkliensDlg.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "ConnectDlg.h"

class CCsetkliensDlg : public CDialogEx
{

public:
    CCsetkliensDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);
    enum { IDD = IDD_CSETKLIENS_DIALOG };
protected:
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

**CsetkliensDlg.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Csetkliens.h"
#include "CsetkliensDlg.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

CCsetkliensDlg::CCsetkliensDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(CCsetkliensDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CCsetkliensDlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL CCsetkliensDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: I was having this same issue, and I was even returning `TRUE`! My problem was that Visual Studio had my default code making my `dlg` a local variable on the stack, rather than a class member on the heap. When the `InitInstance` function exited, my stack instance of `dlg` was deallocated, and I was getting a warning saying the `m_pMainWnd` member was set to `NULL`, causing the application to terminate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning `FALSE` from your application class's [`InitInstance` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae6yx0z0.aspx) tells MFC that initialization failed and the application should terminate.

Change that like to `return TRUE;` and everything should work fine.

```
BOOL CCsetkliensApp::InitInstance()
{
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrls;
    InitCtrls.dwSize = sizeof(InitCtrls);
    InitCtrls.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrls);

    CWinApp::InitInstance();

    if (!AfxSocketInit())
    {
        AfxMessageBox(IDP_SOCKETS_INIT_FAILED);
        return FALSE;
    }

    CShellManager *pShellManager = new CShellManager;

    dlg = new CCsetkliensDlg();
    m_pMainWnd = dlg;
    dlg->Create(CCsetkliensDlg::IDD);
    dlg->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW); // this is not a blocking call!


    if (pShellManager != NULL)
    {
        delete pShellManager;
    }

    return TRUE; // change this one!
}
```

The reason that it works with a modal dialog (shown by calling the `DoModal` method) is because a modal dialog creates its own message loop, which runs until you close the dialog. That means that execution effectively "blocks" at the `DoModal` call without returning control to your `InitInstance` method, so it doesn't return `FALSE` and MFC doesn't quit. At least not until you close the dialog, in which case you *want* it to quit, so everything appears the work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing anything that tells the application to stay alive after opening the modeless window.  You need at least one 'modal' style window, or something else to control termination of the application.

Comment: No. What is needed is a message loop that will dispatch messages to the windows, whether they are modal or not.